# NullReferenceException in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, response

I have the following code:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("PopMsgText");
myCookie.Value = message;
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

It is giving NullReferenceException at the Response line. What could be the reason?

Comment: Cookies collection is not initialized or response is null

Comment: Whre are you using this code? In a Page, User control? in an event handler?

Comment: where/what context you are executing this code?

Comment: @JotaBe In a user control, at a link button click event. One user control is calling others user control's function.

Comment: It's so strange... in that context Response should exists and Cookies must exists in the response. Which is the null object there? Response or Cookies?

Comment: Its resolved. I just changed Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
 to HttpContext.Current.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the `Cookies` property or the `Response` object is null. This could happen depending on where you are calling this code. For example if you attempt to access the `Response` object in a background thread it might be null because there's no HttpContext associated to background threads.